# How to pass a variable from Lua script to Javascript using splash and scrapy?

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, lua, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I was working on a scraping project made of scrapy and splash. I am a newbie in Lua and Javascript. I am in a situation where I need to send a variable from Lua to Javascript. but I am not being able to find out how.

Here is my Lua script

```
 script = """
    function main(splash, args)
        assert(splash:go(args.url))
        pn = tonumber(args.pn)
        assert(splash:wait(10))
        assert(splash:runjs('document.querySelector("#profile-listing-uploads > div:nth-child(2) > ul > li:nth-child("+ pn +") > a").click()'))
        assert(splash:wait(10))
        return {
        html = splash:html()
        }
    end
    """
```

The error I am getting is

```
Bad request to Splash: {'info': {'line_number': 7, 'source': '[string "..."]', 'type': 'LUA_ERROR', 'message': 'Lua error: [string "..."]:7: JS error: "ReferenceError: Can\'t find variable: pn"', 'error': 'JS error: "ReferenceError: Can\'t find variable: pn"'}, 'description': 'Error happened while executing Lua script', 'type': 'ScriptError', 'error': 400}
```

Looks like it's a Javascript error and it is not being able to find the variable pn which is present in Lua script. How can I pass the value of pn to the javascript?

Answer (score 1):

By my count, line 7 of the Lua script is `assert(splash:wait(10))`, but `pn` isn't used there.

If the numbering is off by one, perhaps the error is actually in line 6, `assert(splash:runjs('document.querySelector("#profile-listing-uploads > div:nth-child(2) > ul > li:nth-child("+ pn +") > a").click()'))`. I do not know if there is some Lua function that defines variables in the JavaScript runtime, but you should be able to concatenate the value of the variable `pn` into the JavaScript, like this:

```
assert(splash:runjs('document.querySelector("#profile-listing-uploads > div:nth-child(2) > ul > li:nth-child(' .. pn .. ') > a").click()'))
```

(This will crash if `pn` is `nil`, if `args.pn` wasn't a valid numerical literal in `pn = tonumber(args.pn)`.)

Answer (score 0):

Try accessing your argument like this:

```
pn = tonumber(splash.args.pn)
```

Comment: Tried your solution but it didn't work. If you notice the error, it says it is in the line number 7.